# HTML <a/> tag implement in Android

Tags: android, html, hyperlink

Is it possible to implement this HTML snippet in Android? If yes, then how?

```
<a href="https://icons8.com">Icon pack by Icons8</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost, this is supported:

```
<string name="my_site"><a href="https://icons8.com">Icon pack by Icons8</a></string>
```

Checkout [this](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.se/2011/04/html-in-textviews.html) guide of what you can do with HTML in Android.